# Is it possible to use pundit authorization with graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, pundit

I want to do something like this:

```
authorize record, :some_action
```

In resolving a graphql field or mutation(example is mutation)

```
module Mutations::CreateLink
  CreateLink = GraphQL::Relay::Mutation.define do
    name "CreateLink"

    input_field :name, types.String
    input_field :url, types.String
    input_field :description, types.String

    return_field :link, Types::LinkType

    resolve -> (object, inputs, ctx) {
      Rails::logger.ap ctx[:current_user]
      Rails::logger.ap inputs[:name]
      ctx[:current_user]
      @link = Link.new(name: inputs[:name], url: inputs[:url], description: inputs[:description])
      authorize @link, :create?
      response = {
          link: @link
      }
    }
  end
end
```

When the above is run this error is shown: 
NoMethodError - GraphQL::Relay::Mutation can't define 'authorize'

Normally you write

```
include Pundit
```

In your controller, but adding it to the GraphqlController does not make any difference.

How do i make it so that graphql is aware of pundit and its methods?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `include Pundit` does not work is that includes are added to classes when you include a module and the `authorize` method would not work anyways since its meant to be included in controllers and makes assumptions based on that.

But its really easy to initialize policies manually:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end
end
```

And you can authorize by calling the appropriate method on the policy:

```
unless LinkPolicy.new(ctx[:current_user], @link).create?
  raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "not allowed to create? this #{@link.inspect}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a somewhat slick solution in this blogpost [Graphql ruby and authorization with pundit](https://medium.com/@NickPoorman/graphql-ruby-and-authorization-with-pundit-3d8d2102533d)

It suggests that you add include Pundit in the graphqlcontroller and then add the controller as context like so:

```
context = {
  current_user: current_user,
  pundit: self
}
```

Then the authorize method is exposed like this in resolving fields and mutations:

```
ctx[:pundit].authorize @link, :create?
```

Pundit knows the user as the current_user in the context and throws appropriate errors.

Answer (score 1):

Using a later version of graphql-ruby (I'm using 1.9.17 at the time of this writing), you can define an `authorized?` method in the mutation and include the following...

```
Pundit.authorize context[:current_user], @link, :create?
```

See https://github.com/varvet/pundit/blob/df96d2ae6bcf28991c1501d5ff0bde4c42aa4acd/lib/pundit.rb#L60-L76 for details on the Pundit `authorize` class method.

See https://graphql-ruby.org/mutations/mutation_authorization.html#can-this-user-perform-this-action for details on the `authorized?` method for graphql-ruby

Answer (score 1):

The [paid version](https://graphql.pro/) of `graphql-ruby` has [pundit integration](https://graphql-ruby.org/authorization/pundit_integration.html).

But you can also use `Pundit` manually by calling:

```
Pundit.authorize(context[:current_user], record, :some_action)

Pundit.policy_scope(context[:current_user], RecordClass)
```

However, this won't satisfy `verify_authorized` and `verify_policy_scoped`. For that you need to call `authorize` and `policy_scope` on the controller, similar to @TamRock's answer:

graphql_controller.rb

```rb
class GraphqlController < ApplicationController
  include Pundit::Authorization
  after_action :verify_authorized
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped

  public :policy_scope
  public :authorize

  # ...

  def execute
    # ...

    context = {
      controller: self
    }

    # ...
  end
end
```

Then in the resolver:

```rb
context[:controller].policy_scope(RecordClass)
context[:controller].authorize(record, :some_action)
```

Comment: Thanks,  `public :authorize`, fixed my issue! :)